# Facebook OAuth keeps redirecting to Facebook.com/user_cookie_prompt

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was developing my App and it was all fine all good, but suddenly I couldn't log in with OAuth.

Strangely, I found out that I am unable to log in with OAuth at the Graph Explorer, and then I found out that I cannot log in at all at everywhere.

For example, I cannot log in to canva.com, it redirects me to this address:

https://www.facebook.com/user_cookie_prompt/?back_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv6.0%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fstate%3Dcf07e493-c794-4f02-8777-ac457d63362b%26scope%3Dpublic_profile%252Cemail%26response_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3D525265914179580%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.canva.com%252Foauth%252Fauthorized%252Ffacebook%26ret%3Dlogin%26fbapp_pres%3D0%26logger_id%3D15b708ec-118f-444d-9601-d6406f286b03%26tp%3Dunspecified

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_X2rMcck-6Y

Here is a video of this strange behavior. :(